# Regex Validation with character position

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello I need help with validation using regular expressions in javascript

I need something like this.

The first character should be a designated character like A, B or C only. and the next 3 characters should be numbers.

example: A123, B345, C234.

D123 is not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
var rgx = /^(?:A|B|C)\d{3}$/;

alert('A123'.match(rgx)); // A123
alert('D123'.match(rgx)); // null
alert('B986'.match(rgx)); // B986
```

Breakdown:

- `^` matches the beginning of a string
- `(?:A|B|C)` matches A or B or C but does not capture it
- `\d{3}` matches 3 digits in a row
- `$` matches the end of the string

Therefore `'A12'` would not be valid because there aren't 3 digits, nor would `'  A123'` because of leading whitespace, nor would `'A123 hello'` because the match isn't at the beginning and end of string.

To make it case insensitive, add `i` after the `/` at the end of the regex.

Comment: Thanks works perfectly... another question.. how about if 'A123 hello' would be possible. it still checks the first 4 characters but doesn't check the succeeding ones..

Comment: In that case just remove the `$` from the end.  That way it will only match at the beginning of the string.  If that text can be anywhere in the string, then you can also remove the `^` from the beginning of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this regex:

```
/^[a-c]\d{3}$/i
```